# Hide Testcafe Overlay

Tags: debugging, testing, automated-tests, overlay, testcafe

I'm trying to use testcafe to fill forms on a page.
When the form is filled, I'd like to be able to stop the test with the window still open so a human can review the form before clicking submit.

I can pause the test with `t.debug()` but this locks the page and shows the testcafe controls overlay at the bottom.

Is there a way I can remove this overlay and unlock the page?

I've tried using client functions to hide the element with javascript as follows:

```
test('test_1', async (t) => {
  const hideOverlay = ClientFunction(function() {
    const target = document.querySelector('#root-hammerhead-shadow-ui > div > div');
    target.style.display = 'none';

    return true;
  })

  await t.wait(5000);

  setTimeout(async function() {
    const res = await hideOverlay();
    console.log('-------->', { res });
  }, 6000);

  await t.debug();
});
```

Since no code will be executed after debug is invoked, I thought I could use a settimeout to queue the call to the function that hides the overlay, so that it is queued and only executes after debug is called and the overlay is visible.

Didn't work though :( code didn't execute, got an unhandled promise rejection.
Could really use some help here, thanks :)

Comment: While using t.debug(), there will be an  'Unlock page' button on the testcafe controls overlay at the bottom, you can click it and unlock the page.
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html

Comment: I was hoping there's a way to do this with javascript code

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can unlock the page by clicking the 'Unlock page' button in the footer as @VysakhMohan mentioned in the comment.

Please refer to the [client-side debugging documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html#client-side-debugging) for more details.

Comment: Looking to do this with Javascript, so a user wouldn't need to unlock it.

Comment: The page is locked by default to prevent some accidental actions which may lead to unexpected results. I would prefer to have the page locked.